# Jenkins why stay [ ] after tokenize(', ').join('\n')?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In jenkins pipeline in ENV I have list of hosts

exits YAML with list of hosts

```
matching_hosts:
  - dev-app-0004
  - dev-app-0005
  - dev-app-0006
```

Jenkinfile

```
def jenkins_ci_examples = [:]

 jenkins_ci_examples.project_vars = readYaml file: 'vars/project_vars.yml'

env.target_hosts=jenkins_ci_examples.project_vars.matching_hosts
```

Jenkins log:

```
+ printenv

target_hosts=[dev-app-0004, dev-app-0005, dev-app-0006]
```

after I want to convert list of hosts what to save in file hosts

```
writeFile file: "hosts", text: "[project1]\n" + env.target_hosts.tokenize(', ').join('\n')+ "\n"
sh "cat hosts"
```

in result

```
[project1]
[dev-app-0004
dev-app-0005
dev-app-0006]
```

How take away symbols "[" and "]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in below way :

```
target_hosts=["dev-app-0004", "dev-app-0005", "dev-app-0006"]
writeFile file: 'hosts.txt', text:"[project1]\n" + env.target_hosts.join('\n')+ "\n"
```

**Output**:
[image]

**Edit**:
Based on the question , and without using `"` you can use as below :

```
writeFile file: 'hosts.txt', text:"[project1]\n" + target_hosts.tokenize(', ').join('\n').replaceAll("[\\[*\\]]","")   + "\n"
```

Comment: @Nikolay Baranenko does this work for you

Comment: without "" impossible? I add details for case)

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko yes thats possible, I have updated the answer, it should give the correct result